# Enum type in class diagram (pgf-umlcd)

Tags: pgf-umlcd

I just discovered the package **pgf-umlcd** and I am unable to draw enum types, I tried the obvious:

```
\begin{enum} 
\begin{enumeration}
\begin{enumclass}
```

However none of these work. I did some Google research but was not able to find the correct line of code. Anyone knows?

I add this working code in case it can help.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{class}[text width=7cm]{ClassName}{0,0}
        \attribute{Attribute1 : Type}
        \attribute{Attribute2 : Type}
        \operation{Method1(parameter list) : Returned Type }
        \operation{Method2(parameter list) : Returned Type }
     \end{class}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Kind regards and thank you in advance.
Miguel

Comment: Please add a full example document to your question that can be compiled and that shows a simple diagram with a node in which you want to use an enum type. This would save time for the people interested in answering your questions, and it may prevent compatibility issues.

Comment: OK, I added a working example in case it helps. In my opinion it is just misleading because the code I posted is for classess but what I need is an enum type and I just can´t find the right keyword for it, the author does not show any example on the documentation...maybe it does not exist?

Comment: The answer seems to be in the following webpage, however I do not know what to make of this code, where should I put it? Any help is very much appreciated.    https://github.com/jcb/these-jcb/blob/master/custom_pgf-umlcd.sty

Answer (score 1):

The custom style https://github.com/jcb/these-jcb/blob/master/custom_pgf-umlcd.sty linked by the OP in a comment contains an implementation of enum nodes. This file also contains the original code from `pgf-umlcd`, so it could be used as a replacement (i.e., `\usepackage{custom_pgf-umlcd}` instead of `\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}`) that offers the original functionality of `pgf-umlcd` together with the additional features like enum nodes. However, the file is based on a version of `pgf-umlcd` from 2014, so it lacks recent developments to the package. Therefore it is better to load `pgf-umlcd` normally and copy only the code related to enum classes from the modified package.

The enum functionality consists of a `tikzstyle` and an environment. In the MWE below these are copied. The environment is used like a normal class, and the enumeration items are listed using `\attribute{}` (one for each item).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
% enum style and environment from
% https://github.com/jcb/these-jcb/blob/master/custom_pgf-umlcd.sty
% Author: Jean-Christophe Bach
\tikzstyle{umlcd style enum}=[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, 
every text node part/.style={text centered},
draw, minimum height=2em, umlcolor, minimum width=2cm, text width=4cm,
minimum height=1cm, node distance=2cm]
\newenvironment{enum}[3][]%
{
\begin{classAndInterfaceCommon}{#1}{#2}{#3}
}%
{\node[umlcd style enum, anchor=north] (\umlcdClassName) at (\umlcdClassPos)
    {$<<$enumeration$>>$ \\ \textbf{\umlcdClassName}
\nodepart{second}
\umlcdClassAttributes
};
\end{classAndInterfaceCommon}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{class}[text width=7cm]{ClassName}{0,4}
        \attribute{Attribute1 : Type}
        \attribute{Attribute2 : Type}
        \operation{Method1(parameter list) : Returned Type }
        \operation{Method2(parameter list) : Returned Type }
     \end{class}
     \begin{enum}[text width=7cm]{Colors}{0,0}
     \attribute{Red}
     \attribute{Green}
     \attribute{Blue}
     \end{enum}     
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Marijn